# Buck-Boost Converter Modeling

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, switch-mode-power-supply, buck, buck-boost

I wanted to perform AC analysis for a buck boost converter using SIMetrix/SIMPLIS for simulation,  using this simulator the designer does not need to the average model to get the frequency response of that SMPS, but one can use direclty the switching model. Based on that I have built the circuit below for simulation of a buck-boost converter with the following specifications:

- Vin=10 to 15v.
- Vout=12v,
- Iout=2A max (maximum output current)
- Fsw=100kHz (Switching frequency).
- Crossover frequency at 5kHz
- A double zero at 600Hrz
- A pole à 7kHz
- A pole at 50kHz

[image]

**I set the maximum current through the inductor to be 7A to reset the switching at start up, it is used to set the maximum duty cycle, in this case 90%** (**This current is chose to be (Vin/L)x(Tswx90%)**).

-**My first question is: How do I chose this current and the sense resistor that will limit the current at startup ?**

-**What is the effect of this current limiter on the frequency response of the model?**

When I simulate the model, I got the following transient response of the different probed points:

[image]

If we focus on the transient response graph, we notice that something goes wrong Vout, because the settling of different currents and output voltage is not smooth.

The Verr graph,which is the output of the Type3 compensator shows that its output is oscillating around 0.5v and it does not saturates, but it saturates at start up.

To troubleshoot my circuit, I looked to the frequency response of each bloc.

**- Power Stage Frequency Response without the duty ration generator:**

[image]
It seems to be good and I got the same thing from MATLAB.

**- The Type 3 Frequency Response:**

[image]

The frequency response is perfect which means the  model of Type 3 compensator is correct.

**- Frequency response of duty cycle modulator (encyrcled in blue in the circuit above)**

[image]

Here is the problem, when this gain and phase are added to the power stage, I do not get a nice frequency response of the whole power stage. Because mathematically speaking, this part of circuit is included in the power stage model (transfer function)

What have tried to build another model using voltage controlled current source but I field.

Could anyone explain to me what is this phenomenon and how can I build a modulator without a gain and phase distortion ??

Comment: Make sure your DC sources for your op-amp aren't disabled for AC analysis.  I'm not by my machine right now so I don't remember the exact menu operations to enable, but you should be able to find it.  This has bitten me in SIMPLIS in the past.

Comment: Any help? I still stack in solving this problem